# Eliminar elemento de localStorage con eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

estoy haciendo una app de tareas. Todas las tareas ingresan por un input y se muestran en cards que contienen un boton para eliminarlas. Pero cuando quiero eliminarlas, se eliminan comenzando por la primera, y no la que selecciono con el boton.
Me podrian orientar como puedo hacer?
Gracias

```js
class Tarea{
    constructor (id, name, priori, desc) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.priori = priori
        this.desc = desc
    }
}
//GUARDO EL ARRAY EN EL STORAGE
let arraytask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arrayTask')) || []

// //ACCEDO A LOS ELEMENTOS DEL DOM
const inputName = document.getElementById('input-tarea')
const inputDesc = document.getElementById('input-desc')
let id = 100

//AGREGO LAS TAREAS
for (let tarea of arraytask) {
    id = id + 1;
    $('.panel-card').append(`<div id=card> <h3> ${tarea.name} </h3> ${tarea.desc}<input type=image src="/img/delete.png" id="btn-delete" data-id=${tarea.id}></input> </div> `)
}

//AGREGAR TAREAS
$('#add-btn').on('click', function(event){
    const name = inputName.value
    const priori = selectPriori.value
    const desc = inputDesc.value
    const tarea = new Tarea(id, name, priori, desc)
    const nameValue = inputName.value
    if (nameValue == ''){
        $('#error').append('Debe ingresar una tarea');
        $('#error').fadeOut(2000);
        event.preventDefault();
    } else{
        arraytask.push(tarea)
        localStorage.setItem('arrayTask', JSON.stringify(arraytask))
    }
})
// BOTON PARA ELIMINAR TAREA
$('#btn-delete').on('click', function(event){
    const btn = event.currentTarget
    const task = btn.parentElement
    let id = event.target.parentNode.id
     arraytask.splice(id, 1)
     localStorage.setItem('arrayTask', JSON.stringify(arraytask))
     location.reload()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que por concepto, los Ids son únicos y las clases son las que comparten el mismo nombre para varios elementos, entonces, para que id sea único , concatene el iterador del for en cuestión y agreue como clase btn-delete, en este caso se agrega el iterador al id del botón y al id de la tarjeta

```
id="card"+id 
class="btn-delete" id="btn-delete"+id
```

Después en el evento de borrar, va a asignar el evento a toda la clase .btn-delete

```
$('.btn-delete')
```

ahora dentro del evento click va a añadir

```
let numId = $(this).attr("id"); //aquí hay que extraer sólo el número de ese id
```

después puede concatenar el número captura al id de la tarjeta

```
$("#card"+numId).remove();
```

y listo, ahí se remueve la tarjeta, veo que hay una mezcla de javascript puro y jquery, la solución que acabo de escribir está hecha para jquery